# Reporting Services 2008 Chart DynamicHeight Property Creates Extra Space

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a bar chart with horizontal bars. I used this article to setup the dynamic height property: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/27/charts-with-dynamic-size-based-on-categories-or-data.aspx

Everything looks *fine in the viewer*, but as soon as you go to print layout, pdf, et.al there is about **50% more blank space** below the chart.

I've created a sample report (using AdventureWorks DB) to show what is happening. I placed 3 charts with blue backgrounds, each inside its own rectangle with gray backgrounds. The first chart has an expression in the **DynamicHeight** property, the second chart has a hard coded value in the **DynamicHeight** property of 8.5in, and the third chart has a blank **DynamicHeight** and a 8.5in in the normal Height property. I have it return 15 items to place in the chart.

They all look fine in the viewer like I said before, but go to Print Layout and the first and second charts take up twice the space with half of it being blank below the report.

*I tried to post the .rdl code, but its too much for the size limit.*

---

I have an open ticket to Microsoft that has been escalated.

> We've filed the necessary request to get collaboration from our development team so we should be getting a response regarding this functionality sometime in the next couple days. I'll let you know what they say.

---

Development has later confirmed it was definitely a bug, now are trying to decide if it is worth it to add to the next cumulative update or wait until SSRS 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around until this is fixed, is to place the chart control into a table/tablix.

I added an empty table, deleted the details row and the two extra columns, and added my chart that was giving me problems. Everything appears to re-size correctly now.

Answer (score -1):

try setting up the interactive size, margin and page size. im not sure if it will work but you can try. page size - margin = interactive size. do not exceed from your page size when giving value to your interactive size and margin, this also can cause white spaces in print layout.

hope it helps.

best regards,
cathy